zsh: no matches found: MultiplicateLists(np.array([1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7]))
I would like to import a list in a python function and run the function from the terminal of Visual Studio Code. My function, that I called "MyFunction.py", and that I temporarily saved on the Desktop, is the following one:
def MultiplicateLists(a):
    import numpy as np
    import random
    rand_list=[]
    for i in range(10):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(3,9))
    b = np.array(rand_list)
    result = a * b
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(result)

However, when I try to call and make the function run from the terminal of Visual Studio Code, I get the following error, i.e. "zsh: no matches found":
(anaconda3) (base) xxxyyyzzz@xxx Desktop % python3 MyFunction.py MultiplicateLists(np.array([1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7]))
zsh: no matches found: MultiplicateLists(np.array([1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7]))

Here following a screenshot from Visual Studio Code
enter image description here
Might it be that the command "python3 MyFunction.py MultiplicateLists()" is wrong? How can I fix it?

Parenthesis are special characters in zsh. You have to escape them.

Few things to note down are:-

Calling import inside a function in Python is however generally not recommended as importing modules is a relatively expensive operation.

What you are trying to do is passing argument to the file MyFunction.py which needs to be handled by the code itself as system arguments .Hence to call a function from a Python file from the terminal, you'll need to modify your file to accept command-line arguments or to define a main function that calls your desired function.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_list = list(map(int, sys.argv[1].split(',')))
    a = np.array(input_list)
    MultiplicateLists(a)



Now You can easily call it by the following command:-
python Myfunction.py 1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7


You cannot execute a Python program in that way. You need a main driver part which reads the inputs, creates an array, and passes them in to the MultiplicateLists function.
So add the following to the end of your file:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = []
    for x in map(int, sys.argv[1].split(',')):
        numbers.append(x)

    print(numbers)
    MultiplicateLists(np.array(numbers))

You can now run the script by a command in the following form:
python Myfunction.py 1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7


Just for future readers, I write here down the code that worked for me.
This code employes the solutions of @Prateekshit Jaiswal and @OldBoy, who I thank a lot!
def MultiplicateLists(a):
    import random
    rand_list=[]
    for i in range(10):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(3,9))
    b = np.array(rand_list)
    result = a * b
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(result)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    input_list = list(map(int, sys.argv[1].strip('[]').split(',')))
    a = np.array(input_list)
    MultiplicateLists(a)

Then, in the terminal, I type the following:
% python3 MyFunction.py 1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7

And I get this result:
[1 3 5 6 4 6 7 1 2 7]
[7 4 6 9 6 4 5 7 7 6]
[ 7 12 30 54 24 24 35  7 14 42]


In sys.argv[1].strip('[]').split(','), is strip('[]') strictly necessary? Indeed, list(map(int, sys.argv[1].split(','))) works well too
